# "Permission denied" when manipulating bash variable string with substring expansion

Tags: string, bash, shell, variables, unix

Beginner user here. I have taken in user input as a variable, and I am trying to store certain characters as separate variables. Doing so gives me "permission denied". Any suggestion on how to fix this?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Please enter specific release (EX: 20L2): '
read var
echo $var
xx=$(var:0:1) #should grab the first two digits
xx-=1
yy=$(var:2:1) #should grab the last digit
echo "You have chosen var $var, with X value $xx and Y value $yy"
```

After running:

```
chmod 777 Cleanup1.sh
./Cleanup1.sh
```

I get:

```
./Cleanup1.sh[13]: rel:0:2: permission denied
./Cleanup1.sh[14]: xx-=1: permission denied
./Cleanup1.sh[15]: rel:2:1: permission denied
```

I'm running a OSS/Unix shell via OutsideView. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong and dangerous*** You should revert to sane permissions (probably 755 for your use case) and assess whether there is a risk that untrusted users leveraged this security incident for privilege escalation and/or lateral movement,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- You meant `${var:0:1}`, not `$(var:0:1)`. The latter tries to run a command `var:0:1`, which doesn't exist and leads to you error message.
- The second number isn't the index of the last element, but the length of the extracted string, so to get the first two digits, you need `${var:0:2}`.
- To get the last digit, you can use `${var: -1}` – notice the space between `:` and `-` (requires Bash 4.3, I think<sup>1</sup>).
- Parameter expansion with substrings is a Bashism, so `/bin/sh` might not be able to do it – use `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as your shebang line instead.
- `xx-=1` tries to run a command `xx-=1`; if you want to decrement `xx` by one, use `((--xx))` or `xx=$((xx-1))` instead.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you don't have Bash 4.3 or newer, you can use this instead:

```
${var:${#var}-1}
```

Comment: Very good.  As an aside, the OP should note that, while not causing any immediate problem,  `chmod 777` is generally a bad idea.  For one, there is generally no good reason to give _write_ permission to `other`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your suggestions all helped. I changed my shebang to #!/usr/bin/env bash, but I noticed that I can no longer do ./filename.sh, and instead have to use bash filename.sh. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @SiyanShaikh No, that should still work. As @John1024 points out, to make it executable, you just need `chmod +x`, though.

Comment: @SiyanShaikh What error do you get when trying `/filename.sh`? If you get "-bash: /filename.sh: Permission denied", you need to add execute permission to the script (also read permission, but I assume you have that). If you get a different error, you'd have to let us know what it is.